# OpenCL send data from kernel to host

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm trying to make a kernel, that occasionally will update the host on its progress, since the kernel executes a heavy computational task (will take in the realm of hours to days to complete). However, I haven't found a way to communicate from the kernel to the host, except for `printf`, which makes me believe that such communication is theoretically possible.

So far I've tried using a buffer, which the host will periodically check for new messages, however, it seems that for my Nvidia GPU, any way of accessing the GPU memory while the kernel is still running is locked. I've tried using shared memory, as well as mapping a buffer, to no avail.

I also know about the existence of events in OpenCL, but I'm unsure how to create a user event on the host and pass it to the kernel.

I'm at a dead end here, and any and all help will be appreciated. I don't have a lot experience with OpenCL, so I'm not aware of most of OpenCL's constructs and concepts.

Here is roughly the code I've tried, with buffers: https://pastebin.com/zjPfKGYn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have good reason to do it in a more complicated way, I strongly recommend that you just make your kernel run for a short time only, say 100ms, then save whatever it needs to to global memory, which unlike local or private memory is persistent between kernel calls. I mean make your kernel work in the following way.

```
A. Load state from global buffer
B. Do some work
C. Save state to global buffer
```

Then your host can read the buffer between the kernel calls in a loop.

Comment: the problem is that other than progress tracking, the kernel occasionally will output some integers (its impossible to know how many from the start, it could be anywhere from 10 billion to just one), so i really wish there's a way to send a message from the kernel to the host

Comment: I would still do it the way I suggested. You could allocate some space for the output and return early once it's used up. You don't want to 'message' the host with GB of data. Put it in a buffer, return and let the host read the buffer.

Comment: I think you may need to create a large buffer, then you create a number of sub buffers of increasing size, say |B_{i+1}| = |2*B_i| in size, so you don't have to read the whole big buffer of ints every time if it is in no way full. Thanks for accepting my answer, but I'd be interested to read it if you post an answer yourself once you've solved it for your use case.